# What is the MySQL equivalent of Oracle's Enterprise Manager

Tags: mysql, oracle-enterprise-manager

I understand that Oracle will at some point [add support for MySQL to its Enterprise Manager](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/state-of-the-dolphin-opening-keynote-2010-04-13/) software. However I'd like to know perhaps from other Oracle to MySQL migrants what tools are available for monitoring the queries, activity and resource usage happening on a MySQL database instance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be [MySQL Workbench 5.2](http://wb.mysql.com/).  It's still in Beta but development is moving rapidly.  They are replacing the old MySQL administrator with this all in one tool.

Comment: This looks like a tool for developing on mysql. Enterprise manager is for administrating the database.

Comment: Matthew: Actually, the latest version, 5.2 has administration capabilities as well.